# Existence of pivots that strictly improves the objective value in presence of degeneracy

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

Consider a degenerate LP problem:

$$\min c^Tx \\\text{subject to: }\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$Ax=1\quad a_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$$
$$x\ge0$$

Is it safe to assume given an non-optimal initial basis $B_0$, there is always a sequence of pivots for which the objective value strictly improves until optimality? Considering the convexity of an LP implies $c^TB_i^{-1}1\ge c^T\bar B^{-1}1$ where $\bar B$ is the optimal basis, which I can directly infer that $c^TB_i^{-1}1= c^TB_{i+1}^{-1}1$ iff $B_i^{-1}1=B_{i+1}^{-1}1$.

In absence of cycling, which implies given basis index set $S_i$ and $S_{i+1}$ for $B_i$ and $B_{i+1}$ respectively non improving pivots are when $S_{i+1}\not = S_i$ but $B_{i+1}=PB_i$ where $P$ is permutation matrix.

So, the question reduces to determining the necessity of permuting a given basis for strict improvement of the objective value, or is there always an alternative that improves the objective value without permutation of the basis $B_i$ when LP is degenerate?

If so, that should mean if I search for a pivot I should search for a pivot that strictly improves the objective value and exit if no such pivot exists, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $A_{new}$ a submatrix of A from which we've removed all redundant constraints and their corresponding slack variables. The corresponding linear program, $LP_{new}$, is nondegenerate, so any suboptimal basis in $LP_{new}$ has an improving pivot. Choose any sequence of improving pivots.

Now, reconsidering the original linear program, $LP_{old}$, notice that the sequence of pivots we came up with in the previous paragraph is a feasible sequence of pivots here. There's nothing wrong with letting $LP_{old}$'s extra slack variables sit forever in the basis while we ignore them, because they only need to be nonnegative--and we know they're nonnegative because the feasible regions of $LP_{new}$ and $LP_{old}$ are the same.

This argument should apply for all LPs, not just those where
$Ax=1$, $a_{i,j}∈\{0,1\}$. A sequence of strictly improving pivots up to optimality should exist.

---

**EDIT:**

It does not follow from this argument that, given $any$ suboptimal basis, there exists an improving sequence of pivots. The argument shows that there exists such a sequence starting from any nondegenerate solution (or from the initial BFS, regardless of its degeneracy), but not from all. Just be aware of this if you're trying to employ a practical search strategy, because it sounds like you may be planning on a local search, which may blindly choose pivots that lead to a dead end.

Comment: about your suggestion on local search. given that i have an oracle that produces neighbouring integer basic feasible solutions. can i then be confident that i would reach optimality if i only choose improving pivots in polynomial time given that  $a_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$ and the unknowns are binary.

Comment: If you had, say, two neighboring BFSs with a better objective function value, how would you choose between them? The way you choose is going to matter.

Comment: I think the clearest example of this issue arises when the oracle hands you an improving (but suboptimal) degenerate solution--for which there will be multiple BFSs--and you have to pick which of the bases to use. Depending on which basis you pick, you may be stuck at that suboptimal point, because its basis may differ from all other improving BFSs' bases in more than one way, requiring multiple pivots.

Comment: I get it, there can only be a guaranteed flow of improvement if $A$ is totally unimodular. looks like without $A$ satisfying this, there isn't a tweak in the whole of universe that guarantees a sequence of improvement. Even with an oracle.

Comment: Well, there is a way of guaranteeing a sequence of improvement with an oracle. It's just that the oracle needs to consider more than just a given BFS's neighbors--i.e., it can't be a local search because its blindness might lead it to what I referred to as a "dead end." Rather than only looking at a BFS's neighbors, it will need to consider the neighbor's neighbors and probably the neighbor's neighbor's neighbors and so on.An oracle could definitely give you a strictly improving sequence to optimality by using the method I described.

Comment: If you can find the smallest subset of the constraints which yield the same feasible region, what you'll have is a submatrix of A which: (1) is non-degenerate, since all redundant constraints have been removed, (2) has the same optimal solution, and (3) has the same sequence of pivots which brings us to that optimal solution.